# Need advice: 30+ cron jobs on my PHP, MySQL, JS project. Looking for PHP background worker or alternatives since no Laravel/class components

Tags: cron

I currently have a server running more than 30 cron jobs. These cron jobs are used for various tasks, such as processing receipts after placing orders, generating static reports, resetting credit, and more.

The main reason for having so many cron jobs is that I'm not sure how to trigger these scripts to run on the server instead of running them on the web page. My project is built entirely with PHP, MYSQL, and JavaScript. Based on my research, it seems I may need to find a PHP background worker plugin to initiate these scripts.

It's worth noting that I'm not using the Laravel framework, and my project doesn't have class components. Do you have any recommendations for a PHP background worker or any alternative suggestions if I shouldn't use a background worker?

I have try using API to trigger the script instead of using cron, but still, the progress is long that could not complete in one script, still need looking other suggestion to replace cron.